how do i convert this kotlin code to java
Here is a Piece of code in kotlin:
val paymentConnection = payment.connect {
  connectionSucceed {
        ...
  }
  connectionFailed { throwable ->
        ...
  }
  disconnected {
        ...
  }
}

how can i convert it to Java?
the prototype in java is shown like this:
@NotNull 
public final poolakey.Connection connect(@NotNull kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super poolakey.callback.ConnectionCallback,kotlin.Unit> callback)


Does this answer your question? Call Kotlin function with Lambda parameters in Java

PaymentConnection paymentConnection = payment.connect(new ConnectionCallback() {
  @Override
  public void connectionSucceeded() { }

  @Override
  public void connectionFailed(Throwable throwable) {  }

  @Override
  public void disconnected() { }
});


This is not quite right. First, there is no indication that ConnectionCallback is an open class; if it's the one from here then it's final, and therefore can't be overridden. Also connectionSucceeded is not a no-arg method. It takes a function parameter, which in the OP's Kotlin code it is passed a lambda.

I think this is entirely incorrect. This is a typical Kotlin DSL. We don't provide an implementation of ConnectionCallback with methods like connectionSucceed. It's kind of opposite - we receive such class and we call its methods.

This is a typical Kotlin builder/DSL pattern. In this case connect method allows to configure the connection. We provide the code for the setup as an lambda and the connect method provides the ConnectionCallback object which we use in the lambda to configure the connection. The trick is that the lambda is an extension over ConnectionCallback, so it looks like connect injected their functions and properties into the scope of our lambda. From the Java perspective, the lambda receives the callback simply as its parameter.
I may not be able to provide a fully working example in Java, but it will be something along lines:
var paymentConnection = payment.connect(connectionCallback -> {
    connectionCallback.connectionSucceed(() -> {
        ...
    });

    connectionCallback.connectionFailed(throwable -> {
        ...
    });

    connectionCallback.disconnected(() -> {
        ...
    });
});

